# Como girar um GameObjet sem girar o filho dele?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Queria saber uma forma de girar o objeto sem girar o canvas que está dentro dele.
Meu codigo de Girar está assim:

```
    void FixedUpdate(){
        if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }
```

```
void Flip(){
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

Só que dessa forma está girando tudo o que está dentro do player: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDjRq.jpg
Minha hierarquia: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dizCr.jpg 
Talvez eu consiga girar cada componente individualmente, mas queria saber se tem uma forma melhor.
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho 100% de certeza da resposta mas tenho quase que a resposta para sua pergunta é não.
Provavelmente o jeito mais fácil seria criar um outro gameObject que é pai do seu `player3` e retirar o `Canvas` do player e colocar nesse novo gameObject

```
GameObject
..Player3
....GroundCheck
....AttackPoint
..Canvas
....Health Bar
```

Assim rotacionar o Player não altera ele.

Ou você teria que toda vez que dar o flip no `player` realizar um segundo flip apenas no `canvas`

Comment: Entendi, ai eu teria que fazer um codigo no canvas pra seguir o Objeto ou algo assim? Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: não, você moveria o GameObject pai e como o canvas esta nele, ele move junto